# CSS boxes inline and responsive

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<h3>Title</h3>

<div class="col-1-4">
<img src="" />
<h1>box title</h1>
<p>small text</p>
<div id="login" onclick="OpenPage('link');">Login</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xpccL9h8/

i want to be able to set the title (in the  tags) to be above the boxes and allow all the boxes to display inline and responsively

its not currently showing the titles above the boxes as it should (like they are above in the HTML code)

Comment: So what is problem?? Question is totally unclear please add more details

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe try for `.col-1-4` `display: inline-block;` instead of `float:left`

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kybernaut/786tL4eL/)